# meaning of this passage from The Left Hand of Darkness?

Tags: meaning

> Next come the lords and mayors and representatives, one person, or five, or forty-five, or four hundred, from each Domain and Co-Domain of Karhide, a vast ornate procession that moves to the music of metal horns and hollow blocks of bone and wood and the dry, pure lilting of electric flutes.
>
> —from *The Left Hand of Darkness*, by Ursula Le Guin

What's up with this part: "one person, or five, or forty-five, or four hundred"?

And what does *dry, pure* mean here?

Comment: Could be five here, 400 of that group there. The author creates a drum beat with the insistence in the list.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about the second question?

Comment: The "dry, pure" lilting probably refers to a simple electronic sound emphasizing the fundamental tone sans any coloration from overtones. It's what Le Guin probably imagined from the electronic instruments of the time when she wrote this novel.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the number of people from each Domain and Co-Domain varies. One Co-Domain might be represented by one Lord, perhaps, and no one else. The neighbouring Domain might be represented by a Mayor and three hundred and ninety-nine representatives. Many other combinations would other be possible.

It is uncertain whether the numbers are precise in that the numbers of people adhere strictly to the numbers given or whether there might be six people from one Domain or Co-Domain, fifty-nine from another and two hundred and seventy from another, for instance. Ms Le Guin might well have intended it to be read in this way, it is impossible to say from this short passage, but the idea conveyed is that the number of people from each Domain or Co-Domain varies greatly.

In terms of the sound of the electric flutes 'dry, pure' means that there are very few, if any, harmonics to each note and that the sound has a dry quality. This is as opposed to the sound of an analogue clarinet, for instance, which has many harmonics to each note and has a full sound which could be described as 'moist' or 'limpid'.